# Bump map node giving mesh blocky shadows and no lighting

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

It's been happening the last couple of days, but whenever I attach the Bump node to diffuse or any other property, the mesh becomes darker and it gains dark blocky shadows, it almost looks like I've applied the toon shader on it. No matter how my times I use the subsurface tool, the shadows never smooth out and I never get my bump map effect. 
This is the exact beginning setup that I've done on multiple occasions, but recently it's been wigging out on me, I want to know the reason why it's doing this.

**Edit**  The Second image is me doing the same beginning node setup with the outcome looking way different. There's something I'm missing but I don't know what [image]

[image]

Comment: You are having an incorrect node setup mate, there should be also a glossy shader connected to mix shader and then connect  the bump map to both diffuse and glossy. Only having a mix shader don't make bumps, the result will be the same if you directly connect diffuse to material output.

Comment: See also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60644/how-do-i-add-a-bump-map-to-a-texture-i-made-in-blender

Comment: Also your light position may be incorrect.

Comment: Added a second photo showing an example. I use Mix shader for Fresnel and Glossy. It's worked before.

Comment: Is the object set to smooth shading https://i.stack.imgur.com/RumOW.png? Why do you have an unconnected socket in the mix shader? The input for the bump map shoud be connected to the height socket of the bump node.

Comment: As @cegaton said, connect your image texture to height socket instead of normal. Also change the first dropdown from color to non-color data

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109605/how-to-create-a-buisness-card-with-an-embossed-effect/109644#109644

Comment: Oh well don't I feel silly, sorry 'bout that folks, thanks for help!

Comment: Please do not add "solved" as part of the title or put the answer as part of the question.  **Write a proper answer** in the answers section and mark it as accepted instead. Please take the [tour] to understand how the site works. Read also: [what does it mean when an answer is accepted?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

As cegaton said, connect your **Image texture node** to **Height** socket instead of **Normal**.
Also change the first dropdown from **Color** to **Non-color data**.
[image]